# MongoDB Aggregate Projection working differently than find Projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a question about using a projection in my find query of MongoDB. My question is the following, my documents look like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e59045cded246cb8e8183e"),
    "name" : "Acrobatics",
    "category" : {
        "title" : "Combat",
        "key" : "combat"
    },
    "calculationType" : "Skill",
    "statistics" : "INI",
    "title" : "Acrobatics"
}
```

My aggregate query looks like:

```
db.getCollection('skills').aggregate([
    { $match: { "category.title": "Combat" } },
    { $project: { "_id": 0, "name": 1, "category": "$category.title" } }
]);
```

The result is as you would expect:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Acrobatics",
            "category" : "Combat"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Now I want to do the same projection using the find method instead of the aggregate, my query looks like:

```
db.getCollection('skills').find(
    { "category.key": "combat" },
    { "_id": 0, "name": 1, "category": "$category.title" }
);
```

And the result looks like:

```
[{
    "name" : "Acrobatics",
    "category" : {
        "title" : "Combat",
        "key" : "combat"
    }
}]
```

As you can see with the find the result of the subdocument *category* is not folded. I expected the same *form* as the aggregate function; minus the result and OK properties.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is my expectation just wrong? Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't get exactly same output using `find()` because you can't introduced new field in using the `find()` method. The reason you are even getting that result is because `category` is a field name in your collection. The projection parameter in the [`.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method is use to explicitly include or exclude field form the query result and doesn't and is quite different from the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#project-aggregation) which allow you to reshape your documents or include new computed field in the result.

For example the following:

```js
db.getCollection('skills').find({ "category.key": "combat" }, { "name": 1, "_id": 0, "cat": "$category.title" })
```

Yields

```js
{ "name" : "Acrobatics" }
```

because there is no field named `cat` in your documents. If what you want is only the title field you then use:

```js
db.skills.find({ "category.key": "combat" }, { "name": 1, "_id": 0, "category.title": 1 })
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "name" : "Acrobatics", "category" : { "title" : "Combat" } }
```